React Native Paper: Style FAB like other FAB buttons in group with a label, rather than as an extended FAB
I am using React Native Paper as my styling UI library and ran into an issue with the FAB. Within a FAB.group, I need to be able to put labels next to all the FAB options, but need the visuals to be the same for each of them. When putting a label for the original FAB, it becomes an extended FAB with the text on the right, while the others in the group have the text on the left. Is there a way to put the text on the left of the original FAB without just using an absolute positioning of a Text component and manually putting it there?
I've included the code below, as well as some images.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native"
import { FAB, Portal } from "react-native-paper";

const HomeFAB = ({ onPress, onCreateExperiencePress, onCreateContactPress }) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState({open: false})

   const onStateChange = ({ open }) => setState({ open });

   const { open } = state;

   return (
      <Portal>

         <FAB.Group
            open={open}
            visible
            size="med"
            // label="Create Experience"
            icon={open ? "notebook-outline" : "plus"}
            onPress={() => {
               if (open) {
                  onCreateExperiencePress()
               }
            }}
            color={"white"}
            fabStyle={[!open ? {backgroundColor: "#51bdd4"} : {backgroundColor: 'grey'}]}

            actions={[
               {
                  icon: "account-box", 
                  label: "Create Contact",
                  color: 'white',
                  style: styles.buttonStyle,
                  onPress: () => onCreateContactPress(),
                  size: "med"
               }
            ]}
            onStateChange={onStateChange}
         />


         
      </Portal>


   )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   buttonStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
      borderRadius: 12,
      
   }
});

export default HomeFAB;

Image of FAB before opening
Image of  FAB after opening
I can't use the label attribute or it starts looking like this instead
Image of FAB with label
